# Difference between a "component" and a "plugin" in cakephp 2.1?

Tags: cakephp

what is the difference between a "plugin" and a "component" in cakephp? I have some things that i thought were components - because they are loaded with the

```
var $components = array(...);
```

but now that i have upgraded to cakephp 2.1 (from 1.3) I am told that these are, in fact, "plugins" by the useless error message. Are components just another name for plugins... or something else?

Comment: Mensch is correct. Please post the error to help figure things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components and Plugins are still separate entities in Cake 2.0. [According to the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html) components are "are packages of logic that are shared between controllers", [whereas plugins](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html) are "a combination of controllers, models, and views". Compoments extend the base Component class, while Plugins have their own AppModel and AppController.

Think of a plugin as a separate Cake application sharing the same core libraries with your main application.

Also, in Cake 2.0 [components are handled slightly different](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html#components) from 1.3 (they should have component in their file name, so `SessionComponent.php` instead of `session.php`, for example) and some functions were removed. The `EmailComponent` was deprecated entirely, for example.

The error messages you're getting might refer to third-party components. Which ones are giving you trouble?

Comment: Sigh, the upload and Forum ones - by a chap called Miles. If i wasn't so busy apt hunting i think i might have solved the issues! But thanks for the info! If you have info let me now!