# Authorization adapter was not found in cakePHP

Tags: authentication, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to move my code from local to server
when i try to login into the application

[image]

```
Here is my AppController
class AppController extends Controller{
    /*  Determines what logged-in users access to */
    var $components = array('Auth','Session');

    public function isAuthorized($user){
        return true;
    }

    public function beforeFilter(){
        $userdetails = array();
        $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'matches', 'action' => 'index');
        $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';
        $this->Auth->authError= 'You need permissions to access this page';
        $this->Auth->allow('users');
        $this->set('Auth',$this->Auth);
        $userdetails = $this->Auth->user();
        $this->set('myUser', $userdetails['username']);
        $this->set('myRole', $userdetails['user_role_id']);
        $this->set('pStatus', $userdetails['password_status']);
    }
}


Here is my Login Action in UsersController
public function login(){
        $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
        $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if(empty($id)){
            if($this->request->is('post')){
                if($this->Auth->login()){
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());   
                }else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Username or password');
                }
            }
        }else{
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }   
    }
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The part where you authorise controllers in your `beforeFilter` should be capitalised properly:

So:

`$this->Auth->authorize = 'Controller';`

Instead of:

`$this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';`

That particular statement tries to find `controllerAuthorize.php` and should be looking for `ControllerAuthorize.php`. This doesn't cause a problem on Windows, but it does on Unix systems.

Comment: It seem the old saying "the devil is in the details" is still true. And you're welcome. ;)

Comment: It also goes unnotified on Mac OS X. Just sayin'... ^^