# Getting two main errors when I upgrade cakephp from 1.3 to 2.0

Tags: cakephp, upgrade

I am getting two major errors in almost all the pages when I upgrade cakephp 1.3 to 2.0.

```
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - 
headers already sent by (output started at app/View/Helper/AppHelper.php:1) 
[CORE/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php, line 444]


Fatal Error

Error: Unsupported operand types

File: lib/Cake/View/Helper/FormHelper.php

Line: 1982
```

I have changed the `$form` to  `$this->Form` in all the `.ctp` files. But I am still getting this error.

One more error:

```
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - 
headers already sent by (output started at lib/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php:801) 
[CORE/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php, line 444]
```

Error log

```
Warning: Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /app/View/Helper/AppHelper.php:1) in [/home/dev/public_html/cp/lib/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php, line 444]
Trace:
setcookie - [internal], line ??
CakeResponse::_setCookies() - CORE/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php, line 444
CakeResponse::send() - CORE/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php, line 414
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 167
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 108
```

Comment: You should post the code which is causing this error. It is probably a `$this->Form->{type}` with wrong type of options provided.

Comment: I think you are talking about the second issue " Unsupported operand types". Yes it is something related to the type. I have fixed it. But still getting this error   Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at app/View/Helper/AppHelper.php:1) [CORE/Cake/Network/CakeResponse.php, line 444]

Comment: Check your logs (`/app/tmp/logs`), there should be more information about the error(s).

Comment: I posted my error log above. Please check it.

Comment: That error doesn't provide the desired information... Have you checked the debug log also?

Comment: Nothing in the debug log :(

Comment: The error says output started at `/app/View/Helper/AppHelper.php:1`, so it seems that the `AppHelper.php` is incorrect. Maybe it starts with a space or something like that

Comment: This very useful v1.3 -> 2 migration [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10027619/327074) is possibly related for the FormHelper errors (although it shows a different line of failure)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do something with cookies after the header has been sent (which is what the error says)...are you manipulating cookies at all? If so, try removing (temporarily at least) code that does anything to cookies and see if you can get rid of the error.

It's very hard to see what the exact problem is from the information you've posted, I hope this is some help though.

Comment: Yes checked that also. But nothing like that. Still getting same issue. I am trying to upgrade from cakephp 1.3 to 2.0 :(

Comment: According to error something has been output to the response before the end of webroot/index.php - there shouldn't be much code in that file, you could try debugging there (commenting stuff out etc)